# Multiply two floats registers in spim

Tags: spim

I want to write a small program in spim that calculate the length of circumference of a circle and reads the value of radius from user ... and here is the code

```
    sw $s0, p2
l.s $f6 ,p2
li.s $f2 ,3.4

mul.s $f8, $f2, $f6
```

s0  is the value of radius that entered form user
p  float variable in .data section

after execute the program I have these values in registers f2,f6,f8 (when s0=3) :

```
FP2 = 4059999a
FP6 = 00000003
FP8 = 0000000a
```

is that result true ? and if it is true why  the value in f8 10 not 10.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

0000000a is the hex representation of the floating point number.  It does not mean "10", it means 1.4e-44.

The problem is that you aren't properly converting the integer in $s0 into a float.  Consider the case where $s0 = 3.  Your call to "sw $s0, p2" simply puts the bits 0x00000003 into memory location p2.  Your call to l.s "$f6, p2" puts those same bits in $f6.  However 0x00000003 does not mean "3" as a floating point number, but 4.2x10-45.